# How to vertically center the text in table cell

Tags: html, css

From this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pbfsyqut/

What I want is to center the text containing the image inside the div in a table cell.

I tried adding `vertical align` to the span but it doesnt work:

```
.profile-navigation-bar-list span {
    vertical-align:center;
}
```

how come that vertical align doesnt work? how can I center the text?

Comment: Well, first it's `vertical-align:middle`. You probably meant `text-aling:center`.

Comment: and it should be for image http://jsfiddle.net/pbfsyqut/2/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes thx but how does aligning the image vertically align the text as well?

Comment: @Vucko no its what vitorino did

Comment: as `image` and `span` is a `inline-block` element, `inline-block` elements `vertical align` as per the first elements `vertical-align` property

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin You misunderstood me. You put `vertical-align:center;` which is wrong(there is no `center`) - and I said that you need to use `vertical-align:middle` and that you probably replaced with `text-aling:center`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `image` and `span` is a `inline-block` element, `inline-block` elements can be aligned by adding `vertical align` to the largest element in height

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:first-child{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div>test<br/>test<br/>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

In your example you have added `vertical-align` to second element which is the smallest if the second element was height your `vertical-align` would have worked

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>test<br/>test<br/>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

second element largest

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<div>test<br/>test<br/>test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for.
To center the div is pretty standard just add a `text-align:center` to the parent tr and it is ready.

Now if you want to center only the div and leave the image to the left, please check the [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbfsyqut/11/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.profile-navigation-bar-list span {line-height:25px;}
img{float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make all elements inside div vertical-align: middle

```
.profile-navigation-bar-list div > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I would also remove unnecessary divs.